# Player falls halfway throufh the floor till the outer edge of collider. instead of the inner edge

Tags: unity-game-engine

As you can see in the included video the player falls over the floortile till the outer edge of the floor. Instead it should stop at the inner edge of the tile so it looks like its standing ontop of the tile. Can anyone help? I cant find anything on the internet regarding my issue.

Im sorry if this is a easy fix. Im a beginner. This for a school project :)

Video: https://streamable.com/99jz2o
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3c6aq.png)

[Photo of sprite standing on the wrong edge of the tile.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3c6aq.png)

Edit: I went back to the tile palette and redrew the level. This time selecting the game object + bitmap again. Now it works. Probably the reason why it didn't work was that when I drew the level I had not added Tilemap Collider 2D and Composite Collider 2D. Now redrawing with those 2 components added it works as it should!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your tile map collider. Instead of using this, set empty game objects as children of the objects that make up the . Then, add BoxCollider2Ds to each one, and add scale them to fit the map. If that doesn’t work, then it is either a problem with the rigidbody, or the box collider, make sure that all of the settings are set to default, then slowly change them back, and you will discover what is causing the problem. Then you can comment on this post what variable changed it.

Comment: Thanks! this helped! I went back to the tile palette and redrew the level. This time selecting the game object + bitmap again. Now it works. Probably the reason why it didn't work was that when I drew the level I had not added `Tilemap Collider 2D` and  `Composite Collider 2D`. Now redrawing with those 2 components added it works as it should!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the [Composite Collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CompositeCollider2D.html). The docs specify that they

> do not define an inherent shape. Instead, it merges the shapes of any
> Box Collider 2D or Polygon Collider 2D that you set it up to use

When you attach a `BoxCollider2D` or `PolygonCollider2D`, there is a check box on them that specifies **Used by Composite**. When checking this box, other fields will disappear as they are now controlled by the CompositeCollider.

To use this collider, make a new object that will hold all your other colliders or make a few that hold sections of your map. Give this new parent object a `CompositeCollider2D` and give all the children `BoxCollider2D` or `PolygonCollider2D`. After this, make sure to check the box `Used by Composite` on the children Colliders.

Edit: Sorry just saw you were using a Tilemap. Just make the `CompositeCollider` a parent of your `Tilemap` while keeping the `Used by Composite` checked.

Edit 2: I am not too familiar with Tilemaps with Composite Colliders, but one other solution you can try before re-childing is changing the `Geometry Type` field on your `CompositeCollider` from `Polygons` to `Outlines`.